# What javascript libraries/frameworks have been proven to deliver a great user experience on iPad through PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, cordova

Despite all my arguing in favor of web based, I'm being forced into creating a native iOS business application primarily targetted at iPad.  I thought I was going to have to learn Objective C until I found PhoneGap.

I understand that PhoneGap is nothing but a wrapper for my HTML5 application.  Now I just need to decide how to build this HTML5 application.

I'm looking for a proven approach that delivers a great user experience on iPad.  The people I'll be delivering to will want something that "feels" native.

Here are some of the options I've looked at:

- PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile (attractive but some people have complained about the performance)
- PhoneGap + jQTouch
- PhoneGap + Sencha
- PhoneGap + custom javascript

Have any of these approaches been proven to deliver a native feeling application?  Am I missing an important alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look by just the native feel, then PhoneGap + Sencha is the best

Comment: but it also gives loads of headaches ;)